# concatenate two values in register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am modifying a register page, I need to concatenate two values

[image: UI]

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group">
    <input name="tomo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tomo" required autocomplete="off">
    <span style="font-size: 25px; color: #bfc9d4;" class="input-group-addon"> --- </span>
    <input name="folio" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Folio" required autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

The values are `tomo` and `folio`

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        't_matricula' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'matricula' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        't_matricula' => $data['t_matricula'],
        'numero' => rand(100, 9200),
        'matricula' => $data['tomo'] . $data['folio'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

I must save the `tomo` and `folio` values in the `matricula` field, the problem is that it does not execute the registry, please help.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean that `it does not execute the registry`? Do you have any errors as output? What is exactly going on?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it doesn't output an error, it just resets the log view

Comment: you have `matricula` as a required field for validation ... perhaps you mean to validate the `tomo` and `folio` fields since they are being submitted and not `matricula` ... when validation fails it will redirect 'back' with the errors and if you are not displaying those errors it would just look like the page refreshed

Comment: you have value `matricula` in your form? because you required this field in your code

Comment: @lagbox si, the problem was that it had 'matricula' as validation. thanks